# How to change namespace of a table in HBase

Tags: hbase, hbase-shell

I have a table in default namespace in HBase. I want it change its namespace. Is there a command why which this can be done on HBase shell? I want to skip export and import HBase utility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by changing the namespace while cloning a table.It can be done on shell by running following commands:

```
create_namespace 'New_Namepace'
snapshot 'Test','Test_default_snap'
clone_spanshot 'Test_default_snap','New_Namepace:Test'
```